# grails 2.0 - recommend using Jetty 7 or Jetty 8?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Jetty 8 is in stable release and is now using Servlet Version 3 ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_%28web_server%29)).  Grails 2.0 [indicates](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html#webFeatures) it has been updated to support Servlets Version 3 as well, and [indicates](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html#supportedJavaEEContainers)  Jetty 7 works with Grails 2.0, but makes no reference to Jetty 8 as of yet.  Note the Jetty version information indicates Jetty 7 is Servlets Version 2.5 (not Version 3).

Have you run Grails 2.0 on Jetty 8? Can you give a recommendation on which Jetty version to use with Grails 2.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, Jetty 8 is using Servlet Version 3. To let Grails take advantage of it, you have to set

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0"
```

in your `BuildConfig.groovy`. Go [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#builtInOptions).

Please note that your Servlet 3.0 compiled web application won't run in a servlet container not supporting Servlet Version 3.

To answer your question: Running Grails 2 on Jetty 8 is possible in both flavours - Servlet Version 3.0 or below. I recommend to using it.